# powerBI calculates the sum of zip code automatically

Tags: powerbi

I have an excel sheet with list of few zip codes. Wanted to play with ARCGis 
maps. When I imported my excel sheet with zip code, Power BI automatically calculates sum of all the zip codes and gives me a total. Because of this the zip codes are not getting plotted on the map. I just get total of all zip codes when I drag and drop zip code field into the work area. How do I fix this.? Please help

You can see the sigma sign in the picture.

[image: pic]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches.

1. You can select the field and go to `Modeling -> Properties` to change the `Default Summarization` to `Don't summarize`.

[image: default]

2. You can change the settings of the values to `Don't summarize`.

[image: value]

Comment: Hi @shailuk does this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.